# Depth Stencil buffer mandatory?

Tags: directx11

If I disable depth and stencil buffering, do I have to create and set the depth stencil buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not, calling `ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets` with the DepthStencilView parameter being a null pointer is perfectly valid, and you can still draw fine:

[No Z-Buffer used http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21007284/tris.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21007284/tris.png)

Obviously though, whatever you drew last will be drawn on top of everything else, regardless of its actual Z position - the colorful triangle in the image is behind the white one, but was drawn last.

Comment: great, I use the painters algorithm, so this is no problem. thanks!